# Can I get all the Activities for a given lead id

Tags: api, rest, marketo

I have looked at the get lead activities api. However I cannot get the activity for only 1 lead. I can see that on the UI. I also tried to get lead by id. It does not return the activities. Is there another way to do this without getting all the activities for all the leads?

Thanks

Atul

Answer (score 0):

You can get the activity for one lead using the [getLeadActivity SOAP API endpoint](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/soap/getleadactivity/). However, this is not currently possible with the Marketo REST API.

Comment: Any plans to support this in the Rest API ? Thanks Atul

Comment: It is on our roadmap to build this, but there is no definite timeline.